# jsdoc error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './readme/readme.md'

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have already installed jsdoc with `npm i -D jsdoc` command and created `jsdoc.json` file. In `package.json` file there is script called doc and after doing `npm run doc` jsdoc throws an error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './readme/readme.md'`

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "alphabetdb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "doc": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.10"
  }
}
```

**jsdoc.json**

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": ["src"],
    "includePattern": ".js$",
    "excludePattern": "(node_modules/|docs)"
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": true,
    "monospaceLinks": true
  },
  "opts": {
    "recurse": true,
    "destination": "./docs/",
    "template": "./custom-template",
    "tutorials": "./tutorials",
    "readme": "./readme/readme.md"
  }
}
```

**file tree**

```
node_modules/
src/
    fileSystem.js
index.js
jsdoc.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

Comment: Please provide your directory structure. You may use a tool like `tree` to do that.

Comment: I have already updated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `"readme": "./readme/readme.md"`. Seems like this is an outdated parameter, as it is also not mentioned in the [docs](https://jsdoc.app/about-configuring-jsdoc.html).